# How to update tables in the doctrine symfony 3 database

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I'm studying Symfony 3 in conjunction with sonata-admin-bundle, reached the point when I need to download files (images), installed sonata MediaBundle, BUT! Reached the point when you need to update the database through doctrine: schema: update, and then stuck ... when I try to update the tables I get an error

> **The table with name 'symfony.articles' already exists.**

Googled everything that could be, everywhere, everything rests on the dependence of OneToMany, etc. In general that only did not do - even deleted in all essences of dependence - all the same I receive the same error. I understand that somewhere there is a file with built links, but how to overcome this all? Of course, I can kill everything and create everything first and then start updating the database, but this is not an option! After all, then I will continue to connect the bands and again the same error will come out. Prompt, please the decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a duplicate mapping (annotation/xml/yaml) somewhere in your models. I can't remember the exact syntax that causes this, but that's definitely a starting point.

Use `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` to help find problems.

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
```

I was just able to reproduce this by having a duplicate name definition in my doctrine entities.

[image: table name already exists error]

Comment: I ran the `$ php bin / console doctrine: schema: validate` command and got the same error. Yes, I already have such a table, but I need to add new tables that must be formed from new entities.

Comment: Look at your Doctrine entities at the top where you have the annotations (I assume you're using annotations) defining your classes.  I bet you have two named the same.

`* @ORM\Table(name="articles", indexes={...`

Comment: thank you! I'm find error! In other Entity find annotations with name this table!